# Rewriting Ampersand URLs with IIS 7 Rewriting Module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, iis-7, url-rewriting, ampersand

How can I use an ampersand (`&`) in my url rewrite rules in the web.config file?

I want to rewrite the url:

```
http://www.foo.com/index.asp?SomeParameter=SomeValue&SomeId=00
```

to:

```
http://www.foo.com/Section/Page
```

I wrote the following rule in my web.config:

```
    <rule name="RuleName" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^index.asp?SomeParameter=SomeValue&SomeId=00" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="Section/Page"  appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

But I'm having problems with that Ampersand (`&`) in the input url. When trying to rewrite I Get:

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.

I Tried to parse the ampersand to `%26`, but I get the same errror.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using the HTML ampersand character code `&amp;`